# Revelation 6:15-16 & 19:19

Tags: revelation, messiah

Is John the Revelator writing about the same event or are they two separate events?

Revelation 06: **The Kings of the earth hide themselves in the mountains** from Messiah.
Revelation 19: **The King of the earth gather to make war** against Messiah.

> **And the kings of the earth**, and the great men, and the rich men, and
> the chief captains, and the mighty men, and every bondman, and every
> free man, **hid themselves in the dens and in the rocks of the
> mountains**;
> 16 And said to the mountains and rocks, Fall on us, and hide us from the
> face of him that sitteth on the throne, and from the wrath of the
> Lamb: **(Rev 6:15-16 KJV)**
>
> And I saw the beast, **and the kings of the earth, and their armies,
> gathered together to make war against him that sat on the horse**, and
> against his army. **(Rev 19:19 KJV)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is John writing about the same event or two separate events?

Answer: **These are two entirely separate events**.

> **Revelation 6:15-16**: "Then the kings of the earth and the great men and the commanders and the rich and the strong and every slave and free man hid themselves in the caves and among the rocks of the mountains; and they said to the mountains and to the rocks, 'Fall on us and hide us from the presence of Him who sits on the throne, and from the wrath of the Lamb'"

The imagery in these passages, that of hiding in the mountains and calling for rocks to fall on them, are symbols used for *judgment on Jerusalem*. We can know this because the language parallels events prophesied by Isaiah long before, referring to the imminent destruction of sinful Jerusalem. Notice the similarity:

> **Isaiah 2:19, 21**: “Men will go into caves of the rocks And into holes of the ground Before the terror of the LORD And the splendor of His majesty, When He arises to make the earth tremble... In order to go into the caverns of the rocks and the clefts of the cliffs Before the terror of the LORD and the splendor of His majesty, When He arises to make the earth tremble."

Understandably, though the object of God's wrath is Judah and Jerusalem, the rest of the known world is terrified by the carnage wrought by the Romans during the siege. The prophet Hosea used similar words to describe the judgment against the Northern Kingdom of long ago:

> **Hosea 10:7-8**: “Samaria will be cut off with her king Like a stick on the surface of the water. Also the high places of Aven, the sin of Israel, will be destroyed; Thorn and thistle will grow on their altars; Then they will say to the mountains, 'Cover us!' And to the hills, 'Fall on us!'”

Even more significant, let us not miss the fact that, during His Crucifixion, Christ had this to say to *the people of Israel*:

> **Luke 23:26-31**: “[Jesus said,] “Daughters of **Jerusalem**, stop weeping for Me, but **weep for yourselves** and for your children. For behold, the days are coming when they will say, ‘Blessed are the barren, and the wombs that never bore, and the breasts that never nursed.’ Then they will begin TO SAY TO THE MOUNTAINS, ‘FALL ON US,’ AND TO THE HILLS, ‘COVER US.’ For if they do these things [crucify the Messiah] when the tree is green, what will happen when it is dry? [when God has left them]'” (emphasis added).

It, therefore, seems most plausible that the words spoken in Revelation 6:15-16 refer to the judgment against Jerusalem.

**Now, let us contrast this with the symbolism of Revelation 19**.

> **Revelation 19:15-19**: "From His mouth proceeds a sharp sword with which to strike down the nations, and He will rule them with an iron scepter. He treads the winepress of the fury of the wrath of God the Almighty. <sup>16</sup>And He has a name written on His robe and on His thigh: KING OF KINGS AND LORD OF LORDS.
> <sup>17</sup>Then I saw an angel standing in the sun, and he cried out in a loud voice to all the birds flying overhead, “Come, gather together for the great supper of God, <sup>18</sup>so that you may eat the flesh of kings and commanders and mighty men, of horses and riders, of everyone slave and free, small and great. <sup>**19**</sup>Then I saw the beast and the kings of the earth with their armies assembled to wage war against the One seated on the horse, and against His army."

Verse 15 reveals messianic imagery. The sharp sword coming out of Christ's mouth, also seen in Revelation 1:16, is His Word — Scripture. The Bible is "sharper than any two-edged sword." He will strike every worldly nation, ruling "with a rod of iron." These figurative statements refer to (messianic) Psalm 2:

> **Psalm 2:9**: You shall break them with a rod of iron, You shall shatter them like earthenware.’”

We have learned of God's wrath on *the nations* before:

> **Isaiah 63:3c**: “I also trod them in My anger And trampled them in My wrath; And their lifeblood is sprinkled on My garments, And I stained all My raiment."

Further, this same imagery was predicted in Revelation 14(:17-20), where the anger of the Lord would be poured out on all disobedient nations and peoples — not merely Jerusalem. Leading up to verse 19, verses 17 and 18 are a grotesque description of the destruction of the ungodly. Christ and His armies will conquer, just as the prophet Ezekiel prophetically spoke against *the nations of the earth* plural (referred to as "Gog and Magog" in the chapter):

> **Ezekiel 39:4, 18a**: “You will fall on the mountains of Israel, you and all your troops and the peoples who are with you; I will give you as food to every kind of predatory bird and beast of the field... <sup>18</sup>“You will eat the flesh of mighty men and drink the blood of the princes of the earth"

Here, in Revelation 19, the judgment is against *the nations*, where Christ will have the ultimate victory over the kingdoms of the world.

Thus, the passages in Revelation 6 and 19 are quite different. The first appears to refer to Jerusalem, while the second refers to "the nations" (more specifically, Rome) who are both the objects of God's wrath.

Comment: A very well answer! +1 +✓ Do you draw the conclusion here that the Romans siege in A.D 70 was the sixth seal? Tertullian write in his testimony that John is imprisoned during the reign of Domitian who reigned from A.D. 81 to A.D. 96.

Comment: is the son of man in Ezekiel 39 Jesus? is vers 18 peaking to him; You will eat the flesh of warriors and drink the blood of the leaders of the earth ...

Comment: @DanielDahlberg There are several views on the date. I take the earlier view; I feel the first half of the Book (Rev. 6-11) is referring to the siege. And, that occurred in AD 70. When you start adding the prophecies together (Lk. 23:26-31, Matt. 24., Dan. 9:26-27, and many more), there should be little doubt that Jerusalem is the focus of attention. This was the most severe carnage the world had ever known. In fact, I'm of the opinion that much of Deu. 28:15+ relates to the siege as well. Also, 1) yes, this is the 6th seal, and 2) Ezekiel, the man, appears to be "son of man" throughout.

Comment: Thanks for shearing your views!

Comment: @Daniel You're welcome. I also **share** them occasionally. :-)

Comment: Thanks for both that and the spelling correction, seems not possible to edit the comment from shearing to sharing =)

Comment: @Daniel Just an FYI: There's about a 5-minute window to edit a comment. After that, you may need to delete the original and add your correction to the addition.

Comment: Thanks good then I know in the future. I am just a week old here =)

Answer (score 3):

Revelation 6:

> 12 And I beheld when he had opened the **sixth seal**, and, lo, there was a great earthquake; ...  15And the **kings of the earth**, and the great men, and the rich men, and the chief captains, and the mighty men, and every bondman, and every free man, **hid** themselves in the dens and in the rocks of the mountains;

Revelation 8:

> 1 And when he had opened the **seventh** seal, there was silence in heaven about the space of half an hour.

The kings of the earth hid themselves during the sixth seal.

Revelation 19:

> 19Then I saw the beast and the **kings of the earth** and their armies gathered together to wage war against the rider on the horse and his army.

The kings of the earth wage war outside the sixth seal. They are distinct events.

Comment: Thanks. I have always seen Rev 6:16 as the Kings saw him because they know about him ***and from the wrath of the Lamb*** Any thoughts on how the Kings know from who the wrath comes?

Comment: Why did you capitalize "Kings"?

Comment: a rule for capitalizing of nouns that follow me over to English; Offenbarung des Johannes 5:15 Und de ***Künig*** von dyr Erdn ... Künig = King. (https://bibeltext.com/bairisch/revelation/6.htm)

Comment: from the Lamb. The lamb is a person.

Comment: Good answer! +1.